# Changing language on Firefox does not apply

Tags: firefox, language-support

I selected my language at the preferences menu, but it didn't work (I restarted it several times).

Then I tried to download my package [from mozilla.org](https://www.mozilla.org/el/firefox/all/). But now, I don't know which file to run and how, after unzipping, because everything I tried did not work.

I have an Ubuntu 32bit system.

Comment: Is there a command to unzip and execute a   .tar.bz2 file?

Comment: Do you mean setting the language in "Choose your preferred language for displaying pages"? And does "it didn't work" mean you couldn't see your language on some web page, or that the interface (menus, etc.) didn't change to your language? Also, you need to add what FF version you are using. A screenshot of the incorrect result may help.

Comment: Yes... You are right. This is the one I changed and I see that  it works only on web pages. It does. Thank you about that clarification.That's not what I wanted, though. I want to change the interface of it. Here is my version: Firefox Quantum 62.0.3 (32-bit), Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu canonical-1.0. Now, I have the package. I have it extracted. I cannot execute it. There is no error. It just doesn't run. Maybe I didn't use the right way to do it.

Comment: I presume you got the localized FF version, such as from here:[Ubuntu – Package Search Results -- firefox](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=firefox&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all). You can select the OS version at the top of the page. These seem to be .deb packages so should be easy to install. If you are unsure, you should be able to find out how to install on this site.

Comment: Well, I didn't... I installed it from the link you gave here, and when nothing happened, I uninstalled firefox and then installed the one from your link again. Then, it was in greek, finally! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

That not how its work in Firefox. To change your browser locale (translation) you need to do 2 things:
1) Install Language pack you need from official repo - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/language-tools/
2) Go to about:config special page (yes, type about:config in adressbar and hit enter) and search for intl.locale.requested preference, if none found create one yourself using right click - New - String and set its value to one which corresponds your language.
You can get right lang code on this page http://l10n.mozilla-community.org/webdashboard/

After all done - restart browser.

Comment: Where is the about:config? I couldn't find it, but now I uninstalled and installed firefox in greek. As I understand, the way to change it is not so easy. Not easier than install it in your language at first place. Thank you very much.

Comment: about:config is actual special address in Firefox. Just type it in adressbar and hit enter. You may need to push button agreeing that you will be carefull too (its really hard to break anything unless you do truly random changes in prefs).
On this page you type pref name you need in Search field and apply changes you want).
And yes, changing language in Firefox is little awkward.